# Function that returns words in string not exceeding max number of characters

Tags: javascript, strings, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a robust function that receives a string -- typically a paragraph or two -- and the max number of characters in the output. One condition is to make sure that we return full words and never cut one in half.

Here's the code I have and I feel it needs to be improved. This is normal ES2015/ES6 with no additional libraries.

```
export const shortenTextToSpecifiedNumberOfCharacters = (input, numberOfCharacters) => {

    if (!input) return "";
    else if (input.length <= numberOfCharacters) return input;

    for (var i = numberOfCharacters; i > 0; i--) {
        if (input[i] == ' ') {
            return input.slice(0, i) + ' ...';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this vanilla JavaScript/ES6 or are you using Node.js or other libraries?

Comment: Just vanilla ES2015

Comment: Great! Hope you get some good reviews.

Comment: This code is probably not working properly. a) there's no `return` after a `for` loop, and `input[i] == ' '` may not be achieved. that will result in returning an `undefined`. b) reaching `input[i] == ' '` may still be to early. here's a case: `shorten("lorem ipsum lalala blah a", 10)` will result in `"lorem ipsum lalala blah" instead of "lorem ipsum lalala"...

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: Your case (b) cannot happen, since with those arguments `i` starts counting down from 10, and so the output you'll get will be `"lorem ..."`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you're right about the (b) actually. But (a) still applies...

Comment: @Sam I have rolled back your edit. Please don't change or add to/update the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for the reasoning behind this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code can end up falling out of the loop and implicitly returning `undefined` if there are no spaces within the first `numberOfCharacters` characters in the input string.  You might want to add an explicit `return` statement at the end of the function to handle that case.

Also, in your loop you only test for spaces, not for newlines, tabs or other whitespace characters.  You could simply add tests for those into your `if` statement, like this:

```
if (input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t' || input[i] == '\r' || input[i] == '\n') {
```

but it would be shorter and cleaner to use either `indexOf()`:

```
if (" \t\r\n".indexOf(input[i]) >= 0) {
```

or a regexp test:

```
if (/\s/.test(input[i])) {
```

You may also wish to ensure that `input[i-1]` is *not* a whitespace character.  You could do it like this:

```
const spaces = " \t\r\n";
for (var i = numberOfCharacters; i > 1; i--) {
    if (spaces.indexOf(input[i]) >= 0 && spaces.indexOf(input[i-1]) < 0) {
        return input.slice(0, i) + ' ...';
    }
}
```

or, using a regexp, like this:

```
for (var i = numberOfCharacters; i > 1; i--) {
    if (/\S\s/.test(input.slice(i-1, i+1))) {
        return input.slice(0, i) + ' ...';
    }
}
```

Also note that the output of your function may be up to 4 characters (the length of the `" ..."` suffix) longer than the specified length limit.  If that's not what you want, you may wish to change your `for` loop to:

```
for (var i = numberOfCharacters - 4; i > 1; i--) {
```

Comment: While this code fixes the bug(s) in the original, it's _really_ hard to maintain it in a long run.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko: You're probably right, and I'm not convinced that the single-regexp solution would necessarily have better performance either, since it needs to dynamically reconstruct a new RegExp object on every call. I've removed that part from my answer.

Comment: I really like the updated version's readability improvement. Up voted

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. If I'm following the answer and the comments correctly, the final version of the function would look like the one I posted in the UPDATE section of original post. I'm not using `RegEx` for better performance -- as per comments.

Comment: I'm seeing two interesting behavior here. This code -- without Regex -- seems to be counting the line breaks as well. Secondly, it's not adding the ellipsis at the end. I'm thinking it may be a better idea to use RegEx to take the text without any line breaks, then count the number of characters.

Comment: @Sam: How do you actually want line breaks (and/or tabs) to be handled? In my answer, I assumed it would be best to treat them the same way as spaces, even though your original code doesn't do that. If that's not the case, it should be easy enough to fix, but first I need to know what actually should happen if there's a line break near the point where the string should be cut off.